# Share image in instagram via Intent with json url

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share image to instagram via Intent with json image but i need to parse my json image  here's my code

```
private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String imageUrl ,String captionText){

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    share.setType(type);       

     URL url = null;
        Bitmap bmp1 = null;
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageUrl);
            bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,byteArray);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,captionText);
    share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the network operation in your UI thread. Put your code to the another thread, e.g `AsyncTask`

```
// move following operation to another thread
bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

After you retrieve the image, set your share intent `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` to the Uri of your image file. Following is the code copy from [Instagram official document](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/#).

```
String type = "video/*";
String filename = "/myVideo.mp4";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;
String captionText = "<< media caption >>";

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath, captionText);

private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath, String caption){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI and the caption to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

Comment: It is possible to put url link (my image stored on server) to  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); ?
I got crash when:
Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlPhoto));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

Comment: As my answer above, you should download the image firstly, then use the explicit intent to share.